# IQ test question-black and white squares

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix

Can anyone help with this question?

[image]

Comment: This seems like a question from elsewhere. Pls site the source if this is the case. Also, please do not post a question in an active competition to ensure fairness. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The answer is *probably*

> D

since the boxes move as follows

> [image]

...at least that pattern matches and it is reasonably simple.